# How to find 00000000 in memory with python the way C does using while != 00000000

Tags: python, c, memory, string-length

every time a computer stores a string in memory, for example the word 'apple', it's not using 5 characters, it's using 6 characters, `'a','p','p','l', 'e' + 'null'` therefore putting 00000000 aka '\0' in the last byte.
so here is the code that would work in c:

```
// assuming string A = 'apple'
int count = 0;
while (A[count] != '\0')
{
  n++;
}
```

so i tried the following code in python, it did not work, what went wrong?

```
A = 'apple'
count = 0
while A[count] != '\0':
    count+=1

print(count)
```

Note: the point here is not to get the length, the point is how do i get the length using while != 00000000

Additional Note: how does python store strings in memory, does it put 00000000 in the end like c does? if it doesn't ,lets say i put a 00000000 in memory using c, then how do i find that 00000000 in memory with python?

Comment: `python` `strings` are not `NULL` `delimitered`

Comment: Python does not store strings that way.  That is a C convention.

Comment: You get the length of a python string with `len`, period. There is only one obvious way to do it. BTW - in C one should use `strlen` as the compiler would more readily know how to optimize it.

Comment: Python and C are two different languages, you know, with different syntax and semantics.

Comment: but the string is stored in memory right? or does python not store strings in memory the way c does? so where is the string, how do i find that 00000000 in memory

Comment: Python is a high level language, if you want to do things like that then use C.  *"every time a computer stores a string in memory...."* - what you show is a language convention in C, it does not necessarily apply to other languages, many of which store a length rather than use a delimiter.  "*a computer*" is not specifically storing a string, it only knows about bit patterns, 1s and 0s, it is up to the application to decide what they represent.

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't null-terminate strings; the metadata is stored elsewhere.

If you're looking to get the length of a string, you can use `count = len(A)`

Comment: so how do i make it work, if i have to use while != '\n'

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're looking to accomplish; can you give an example of what your input looks like, and what you'd like as your output?

If you have a string you want to split up into multiple strings with a delimiter, the `split` function might be what you're looking for. (https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split)

Otherwise, if you're just looking at individual strings, they're already separated for you; one of the nice things about Python is that it handles a lot of the weirdness about strings/arrays/pointers that require careful handling in C.

Comment: how does python store strings in memory, does it put 00000000 in the end like c does? if it doesn't ,lets say i put a 00000000 in memory using c, then how do i find that 00000000 in memory with python?

Comment: The idea of "access in memory" for Python is a bit nonsensical; by the time you hit python code, it tends to be pretty far removed from the actual memory implementation. I wouldn't hold out hope on ever being able to find that null-terminating byte (if it even exists; they might be prepending strings with length information instead)